# запуск нескольких скриптов, используя nohup

Tags: ubuntu

Чтобы запустить свой проект, мне нужно запускать 3 файла - **test1.py**, **test2.py**, **test3.py** (к примеру).

Для этого я использую `nohup python3 test1.py &> test1.log &` и так 3 раза.

Скажите, пожалуйста, какой должна быть команда, чтобы запустить сразу 3 скрипта?

Answer (score 1):

например, можно воспользоваться оператором цикла:

```
$ for i in 1 2 3; do nohup python3 test$i.py &> test$i.log & done
[1] 15560
[2] 15561
[3] 15562
```